# Apache KeepAlive best practice and configuration

Tags: apache

I would like to know if there is a way on apache to set different keepalivetimeout for specefic request.

I have have built a distributed infrastructure on Amazon Web Service, consisting of a load balancer (aws elb) in front of a group of apache web servers installed on AWS ec2 instances.

I have on my servers, I have a php programme generating pages for users. I've noticed that when I call this script through a browser, the connection ends in exactly 60s, before the generation process ends.

I've searched and find the solution by modifying the load balancer **idle connection timeout** which defaults to **60s**, and set to **360s** and now the page loading is OK.

But Amazon  recommend to enable the keep-alive the web server settings or in the kernel settings for your EC2 instances, as Keep-alive, when enabled, enables the load balancer to re-use connections to your back-end instance, which reduces the CPU utilization

And then I have to set a **KeepAliveTimeOut** on my backends greater than the ELB idle connection timeout.
But not all the request take such time to achieve, and would like to set a specific **KeepAliveTimeOut** for the resquest taking more time on my apache backend server.

For exemple, if my website address is http://www.example.com and I have a statistic page at http://www.example.com/admin_index.php?page=ADMIN_STATS101, I would like to leave the default **KeepAliveTimeOut** for http://www.example.com and set a specific value for http://www.example.com/admin_index.php?page=ADMIN_STATS101

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used the apache global configuration and set a keepalive timeout a bit greater than the the ELB idle connection timeout.

Regards